# Is there a way to put each attribute of an xml tag on new line using DOM parser?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have written down a DOM parser in java which reads tags and attributes from 1 xml file, makes some changes to them, and finally writes them down to a new xml file. The problem lies with the readability. In the original xml file, for every tag, each attribute is on a separate line making the xml quite readable and easier to manually make changes. On the other hand, the new xml file that is being filled by my DOM parser has all the attributes of a tag on the same line making the xml very difficult to manually comprehend and make changes to due to the abundance of both tags and their attributes. I was thinking if there is a way to put every attribute of a tag on a separate line through DOM? Or do I have to use some other parser which provides this capability?

Current xml file -

```
<tag id="1" name="a" age="3" />
```

And, I want my xml to look like -

```
<tag
    id="1"
    name="a"
    age="3"
/>
```

Comment: The [org.w3c.dom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) API does not provide a way to model this. You would have to write your own serialization mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to build a java parser to do the same.